# Javascript or jQuery - Change href with # and give it onclick

Tags: href, edit

I have a problem. Is there a way to change every a href, which has class "primary-action" with "#", and also give it `onclick="alert('myalert message');"` ?

It can be jQuery or Javascript.

I am realy desperate here. I don't have time to learn javascript for this one thing right now, and realy need help.

Thank you to anyone who can help, or atleast try.

Comment: You dont want # link in <a> ? Just want onclick alert?

Comment: Yes. Currently it's `<a class="primary-action" target="_blank" href="myorderpage.com">ORDER NOW</a>`. I'd like to be able to remove href completely, and give it onclick alert.

Comment: i have updated the complete solution, try

Answer (score 0):

Here is the permanent solution for multiple URLs:

Suppose You have three `<a>` tags in one page:

```
<a href="test.com" class="primary-action" onclick="alert('your alert message');">test</a>
<a href="test.com" class="primary-action" onclick="alert('your alert message');">test</a>
<a href="test.com" class="primary-action" onclick="alert('your alert message');">test</a>
```

**Your JQuery Code**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.primary-action').click(function(){
    return false;    
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: On my site I have alot of `<a class="primary-action" target="_blank" href="myorderpage.com">ORDER NOW</a>` buttons. I need to be able to change them all at once, with code I can comment in and out. I need to remove href, and give it onclick alert.

Comment: No. All on one page, same file aswell.

Comment: I think you must need to replace them as I mentioned I dont think if href is set how can I stop to redirect... if u have only one page than repalce them

Comment: Hm, even adding onclick='alert ();' to each link, when I click it, it still opens empty alert.

Comment: Add js function or add some text on it if u dont want function

Comment: Then I'd have to edit all links every time I want to display or remove the alert. I was looking for a way to add alert to all links at once. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thats way I used a js function call alert once